# Matching patterns in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, pattern-matching

My data looks like this:

```
                         S  
0101001010000000000000000100111100000000000011101100010101010
1001010000000001100000000100000000000100000010101110101010010
1101010101010010000000000100000000100101010010110101010101011
0000000000000000001000000111000110000000000000000000000000000
```

the S indicates the column from which I am talking. It is col 26. All four rows share a 1 at that position.

I would need to be able to count for each row from 2 to 4:

- How many columns to the left and right are the same as row 1?

For row 2 it would be 3 to the right (as it reaches 1/0) and 8 to the left (as it reaches 0/1).

The result for every row should be entered into a matrix like this:

```
row2 8 3
row3 11 9
```

Is there a fast and efficient way to do that? The matrix I am dealing with is very large.

Comment: well I provided some data and it is perfectly reproducdeabl....

Comment: no col 26 is input...just really need an eedfficient way to serach for the matching 0 1 around that colum

Comment: Reproducing your data was pretty bothersome to me. -1 for that.

Comment: @Roland: Learn to use `scan` for these input tasks.

Comment: @BondedDust And then use `strsplit` and then `as.integer` with `apply` ...? No, it's the OP's duty to make import easy.

Comment: Well, `scan` is not committing one to use `strsplit` or `sapply` or `rle`. It's just bypassing the need to set up read.fwf properly, which I agree is a hassle. Just trying to save _your_ time, man.

Answer (score 5):

If you need something fast, you could use Rcpp:

```
mat <- as.matrix(read.fwf(textConnection("0101001010000000000000000100111100000000000011101100010101010
1001010000000001100000000100000000000100000010101110101010010
1101010101010010000000000100000000100101010010110101010101011
0000000000000000001000000111000110000000000000000000000000000"), widths = rep(1, 61)))


library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
    IntegerMatrix countLR(const LogicalMatrix& mat, const int S) {
       const int nr(mat.nrow()), nc(mat.ncol());
       IntegerMatrix res(nr - 1, 2);
       for(int i=1; i<nr;i++){
         for(int j=S-2; j>=0;j--) {
           if (mat(0,j) != mat(i,j)) break;
           else res(i-1,0)++;
         }
         for(int j=S; j<nc;j++) {
           if (mat(0,j) != mat(i,j)) break;
           else res(i-1,1)++;
         }
       }
       return(res);
    }' ) 


countLR(mat, 26)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    8    2
#[2,]   10    2
#[3,]    6    0
```

I assumed that column 26 itself doesn't count for the result. I also assumed that the matrix can only contain 0/1 (i.e., boolean) values. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Very useful. That's certainly going to outperform my effort. Like you I thought the problem description was to compare to first row, but unlike you I thought he wanted to include the counts of the matching ones at position 26.

Comment: @BondedDust Well, I assumed the verbal description after the bullet point would be correct. I also thought about using `rle`, but for a huge matrix that wastes a lot if you are only interested in the first run length.

Comment: Right on both counts. The efficiency of your approach would only grow as the size of these strings increased.

Comment: @Roland very nice ...the ony problem is that I get the following error...Error: not compatible with requested type...the matrix I am using is vast so the problem is that iam storing it as a Matrix (capital M intended)

Comment: @Roland c is there any way this would work on a normal Matrix from the Matrix librar

Comment: Yes, of course this can be adjusted to work with sparse matrices. RcppArmadillo should be useful for this.

Comment: @Roland well Is hould have mentioned that in the question and I do have to say that I am really sorry but the way the solution is presented now does not really work - although my question was not particularly clear. Do you think you could maybe edit the answer? I would be really most gratef

Comment: @heinheo Sorry, but that would be a non-trivial amount of work for me. SO is not a code-writing service. I showed you an approach and now you are expected to make this work for you. If you want someone to do your work for you, you need to compensate them somehow for that. Usually, you'd offer them money. (But don't bother offering that to me. I'm way to expensive.)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy with `strsplit` and `rle` to pull apart and assemble this data:

```
>                          S  <- scan(what="")  #input of character mode
1:     0101001010000000000000000100111100000000000011101100010101010
2:     1001010000000001100000000100000000000100000010101110101010010
3:     1101010101010010000000000100000000100101010010110101010101011
4:     0000000000000000001000000111000110000000000000000000000000000
5: 
s2 <- strsplit(S, split="")
sapply(s2, "[[", 26)  # verify the 26th position is all ones
#[1] "1" "1" "1" "1"

#length of strings from 26th postion to right
rtlen <- length(s2[[1]])-(26-1)

# Pick from the `rle` $values where values TRUE
rle( tail( s2[[1]] == s2[[2]], rtlen) )
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:11] 3 4 5 1 7 1 4 1 1 6 ...
  values : logi [1:11] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
```

Now that you have an algorithm for a single instance, you can iterate of the rest of the items in `s2`. To do the backwards look I just did the same operation on a `rev`-ersed section of the strings.

```
m<-matrix(NA, 3,2);
for (i in 2:4) { m[i-1,2] <- rle(tail( s2[[1]] == s2[[i]], rtlen) )$lengths[1]
                 m[i-1, 1] <- rle( rev( head( s2[[1]] == s2[[i]], 26)) )$lengths[1] }
m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9    3  # I think you counted wrong
[2,]   11    3
[3,]    7    1
```

Notice that I was comparing each one to the first row and your results suggest you were doing something else...perhaps comparing to the row above. That could easily be done instead with only a very small mod to the code indices for choice of the comparison vector:

```
m<-matrix(NA, 3,2);
for (i in 2:4) { m[i-1,2] <- rle(tail( s2[[i-1]] == s2[[i]], rtlen) )$lengths[1]
                 m[i-1, 1] <- rle( rev( head( s2[[i-1]] == s2[[i]], 26)) )$lengths[1] }
m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9    3
[2,]    9    9  #Again I think you may have miscounted. Easy to do, eh?
[3,]    7    1
```

Comment: is is possible ot get this also in a version where s2 is matrix? even maybe vompatible with the Matrix package in R

Comment: The transpose of data.matrix(data.frame(s2)) might be what you want. Those items would each be a column if you didn't take the transpose. Your example's a dense matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This problem intrigued me. Since the matrix is binary, it's far more efficient to pack the matrix into a raw matrix than it is to use sparse matrices. It means that the storage for a 1,000 x 21,000,000 pattern matrix is approx. 2.4 GiB (`print(object.size(raw(1000 * 21000000 / 8)), units = "GB")`).

The following should be a relatively efficient way to tackle the problem. The Rcpp code takes a raw matrix which indicates the differences between the first row of the original matrix and the other rows. For efficiency in the R code, it's actually arranged with the patterns in columns rather than rows. The other functions help to convert existing sparse or regular matrices into packed ones and to read a matrix directly from a file.

```
library("Rcpp")
library("Matrix")

writeLines("0101001010000000000000000100111100000000000011101100010101010
1001010000000001100000000100000000000100000010101110101010010
1101010101010010000000000100000000100101010010110101010101011
0000000000000000001000000111000110000000000000000000000000000", "example.txt")

cppFunction('
    IntegerMatrix countLRPacked(IntegerMatrix mat, long S) {
      long l = S - 2;
      long r = S;
      long i, cl, cr;
      int nr(mat.nrow()), nc(mat.ncol());
      IntegerMatrix res(nc, 2);
      for(int i=0; i<nc;i++){
        // First the left side
        // Work out which byte is the first to have a 1 in it
        long j = l >> 3;
        int x = mat(j, i) & ((1 << ((l & 7) + 1)) - 1);
        long cl = l & 7;
        while(j > 0 && !x) {
          j --;
          x = mat(j, i);
          cl += 8;
        }
        // Then work out where the 1 is in the byte
        while (x >>= 1) --cl;
        // Now the right side
        j = r >> 3;
        x = mat(j, i) & ~((1 << ((r & 7))) - 1);
        cr = 8 - (r & 7);
        while(j < (nr-1) && !x) {
          j ++;
          x = mat(j, i);
          cr += 8;
        }
        cr--;
        while (x = (x << 1) & 0xff) --cr;
        res(i, 0) = cl;
        res(i, 1) = cr;
      }
      return(res);
    }')

# Reads a binary matrix from file or character vector
# Borrows the first bit of code from read.table
readBinaryMatrix <- function(file = NULL, text = NULL) {
  if (missing(file) && !missing(text)) {
    file <- textConnection(text)
    on.exit(close(file))
  }
  if (is.character(file)) {
    file <- file(file, "rt")
    on.exit(close(file))
  }
  if (!inherits(file, "connection")) 
    stop("'file' must be a character string or connection")
  if (!isOpen(file, "rt")) {
    open(file, "rt")
    on.exit(close(file))
  }
  lst <- list()
  i <- 1
  while(length(line <- readLines(file, n = 1)) > 0) {
    lst[[i]] <- packRow(as.integer(strsplit(line, "", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]))
    i <- i + 1
  }
  do.call("cbind", lst)
}

# Converts a binary integer vector into a packed raw vector,
# padding out at the end to make the input length a multiple of 8
packRow <- function(row) {
  packBits(as.raw(c(row, rep(0, (8 - length(row)) %% 8 ))))
}

# Converts a binary integer matrix to a packed raw matrix
# Note the matrix is transposed (makes the subsequent xor more efficient)
packMatrix <- function(mat) {
  stopifnot(class(mat) %in% c("matrix", "dgCMatrix"))
  apply(mat, 1, packRow)
}

# Takes either a packed raw matrix or a binary integer matrix, uses xor to compare all the first row
# with the others and then hands it over to the Rcpp code for processing
countLR <- function(mat, S) {
  stopifnot(class(mat) %in% c("matrix", "dgCMatrix"))
  if (storage.mode(mat) != "raw") {
    mat <- packMatrix(mat)
  }
  stopifnot(8 * nrow(mat) > S)
  y <- xor(mat[, -1, drop = FALSE], mat[, 1, drop = TRUE])
  countLRPacked(y, S)
}

sMat <- Matrix(as.matrix(read.fwf("example.txt", widths = rep(1, 61))))
pMat <- readBinaryMatrix("example.txt")

countLR(sMat, 26)
countLR(pMat, 26)
```

You should note that the width of the pattern matrix is right-padded to a multiple of 8, so if the patterns match all the way to the right hand side this will result in the right hand count being possibly a bit high. This could be corrected if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Slow R version to do this (moved from duplicate):

```
countLR <- function(mat, S) {
  mat2 <-  mat[1, ] != t(mat[-1, , drop = FALSE])
  l <- apply(mat2[(S - 1):1, ], 2, function(x) which(x)[1] - 1)
  l[is.na(l)] <- S - 1
  r <- apply(mat2[(S + 1):nrow(mat2), ], 2, function(x) which(x)[1] - 1)
  r[is.na(l)] <- ncol(mat) - S
  cbind(l, r)
}
```